# jquery ajax value with special chars

Tags: jquery, ajax, escaping

I am using autocomplete to fill a form and then post data to a script with ajax.

```
$('#clientName').autocomplete({ 
                    source:clients, 
                    minLength:2, 
                    select: function(e,i){ 
                            $.ajax({
                                    type:"POST",
                                    data:"id="+i.item.value+"&ticket=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>",
//......
```

my problem is that in a few cases, i.item.value = "Red & Blue".  How can i escape the & so that the post carries all the data. as of now its getting cut off to post "Red ".

Answer (score -1):

to solve this problem use escape(i.item.value);